# Unable to view Database with Sqlite plugin Phonegap - no file extension

Tags: eclipse, cordova, android-sqlite, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap to create an app and am unable to view the database with the sql lite plugin (http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse). Unfortunately, even though I can find the database that my app has created, for some reason labelled as 1 I cannot use the viewer. I can use the viewer on the Databases.db file. Looks like the problem is that it doesn't have the db extension?? Why can't I view the DB from within Eclipse? Driving me crazy, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The app is successfully creating a database, storing and pulling information out of it so I know it is working correctly, I just need to be able to view it to develop further more easily.

Here's what it looks like in Eclipse, note that the sql lite button is greyed out and the file is just 1 instead of 1.db as I would expect. I can't find anyone else experiencing the same problem...

[image]

Comment: I'm not using eclipse and we've set things up so if the app runs on the phone it uses SQLite and if its in the browser its WebSQL.We can see the WebSQL DB in the Chrome dev tools but not the SQLite one - we're "blind" like you. If you get the answer I'd love to know too!

Comment: Hey thanks, can you use the same code etc to do this? Do you have a link to documentation, would be good to at least be able to develop it in the browser - I hear WebSQL is being deprecated?

Comment: WOW so you can see everything in the browser from the resources tab in chrome! I had no idea. This helps a lot.

Comment: Yeah, it's chrome://inspect in the address bar. Pretty cool really.